# how can i make sort divs in a certain way

Tags: django

I'm making a todo app with django and every todo has a bootstrap card with todo items in a list but when I add todos they keep squeezing next to each other so how can I make it that when there are 3 divs in a row it makes a new row for the rest of the divs

I tried searching the internet and stack overflow but found nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `display:flex` along with `flex-wrap:wrap` property to parent div.

Here is the sample code:

```
.parent{
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
 }
.child{
     width: 33%;
     gap: 10px;
     height: 100px;
     background: black;
     border: 2px solid white;
}



<div class="parent">
 <div class="child"></div>
 <div class="child"></div>
 <div class="child"></div>
 <div class="child"></div>
 <div class="child"></div>
 <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

When the first row is filled with children according to width, the next child will come on next now.

Also, you can use `display:grid`:

```
.parenet{
    display:grid;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 33% 33% 33%;

}
```